# How to translate JQuery in Javascript to ScalaJS (scalajs-jquery)

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui, scala.js

In my ScalaJS project I use [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com) with [scala-js-jquery](https://github.com/sjrd/scala-js-jquery)

I use this to monkey patch JQuery:

```
  // Monkey patching JQuery
  @js.native
  trait SemanticJQuery extends JQuery {
    def dropdown(params: js.Any*): SemanticJQuery = js.native
    def popup(params: js.Any*): SemanticJQuery = js.native
    // and more
  }

  // Monkey patching JQuery with implicit conversion
  implicit def jq2semantic(jq: JQuery): SemanticJQuery = jq.asInstanceOf[SemanticJQuery]
```

For example `$('select.dropdown').dropdown();`

translates to `jQuery(".ui.dropdown").dropdown(js.Dynamic.literal(on = "hover"))`.

My problem now is how to translate this:

```
$('.ui.form')
  .form({
    fields: {
      dog: {
        identifier: 'dog',
        rules: [
          {
            type: 'adminLevel[2]',
            prompt: 'You must be at least a level-2 admin to add a dog'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the easier Question #2 first (someone else might tackle #1): the key thing to keep in mind is that it's really a *JavaScript* data structure; thinking of it as JSON is a distraction. So you usually instantiate it using a strongly-typed facade, like the rest of JavaScript.

You can find the key documentation [here](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/sjs-defined-js-classes.html), but roughly speaking the facade looks something like:

```
trait Rules extends js.Object {
  def `type`: String
  def prompt: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined
}
```

I'm taking `type` as mandatory here, and `prompt` as optional, to show the difference in how you handle those kinds of fields. (And since "type" is a keyword in Scala, you have to work around that; I *think* backticks will work.)

You then instantiate it by creating an anonymous subclass instance, like this:

```
new Rules {
  override val `type` = "adminLevel[2]"
  override val prompt = "You must be at least a level-2 admin to add a dog"
}
```

Basically, it's fairly ordinary Scala, but that `extends js.Object` is compiler magic -- it tells the compiler that the output should be a JavaScript-readable type, instead of an internal Scala one.

For the outer wrappers, it's basically the same deal -- a deeply-nested structure like this is a slight hassle, but it's basically just a matter of creating a little facade trait for each strongly-typed level.

For weakly-typed levels (eg, `dog`, which I assume isn't defined in the library), you probably want to use `js.Dynamic.literal`, which lets you create any arbitrary JavaScript data structure, with no strong typing at all. (You can do this to create `Rules` as well, of course, but you lose much of the benefit of using Scala if you use this to excess.)

Note that the details of the above vary depending on which version of Scala.js you are using -- see the docs for details. But that's broadly how it works...

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of Justin du Coeur it worked!

Just for completeness here is the whole solution (as it is a combination of static and dynamic parts):

```
trait Form extends js.Object {
  def fields: js.Object
}

trait Field extends js.Object {
  def identifier: String
  def rules: js.Array[Rule]
}

trait Rule extends js.Object {
  def `type`: String
  def prompt: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined
}
```

Here is its usage - check the dynamic `cardNumber` and `cardCVC`:

```
val form = new Form {
  val fields: js.Object = js.Dynamic.literal (
    cardNumber = new Field {
      val identifier: String = "cardNumber"
      val rules: js.Array[Rule] = js.Array(new Rule {
        val `type`: String = "empty"
      })
    },
    cardCVC = new Field {
      val identifier: String = "cardCVC"
      val rules: js.Array[Rule] = js.Array(new Rule {
        val `type`: String = "validate['cardCVC']"
        override val prompt = "You must a valid CVC - see ..."
      })
    }
)}

jQuery(".ui.form").form(form)
```